# Multiple instances of Spyder on Mac option not working

Tags: spyder, multiple-instances

I would like to run multiple instances of Spyder on my mac and have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com).

[Unfortunately, Spyder is not allowing me to de-select "Use a single instance."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9zDX.png)

Are there work arounds or any Spyder developers out there who can help me out?

Thanks.

Other things that I have tried:

I have tried calling "spyder --new-instance", "spyder3 --new-instance", and "open -a Spyder --new-instance" in my terminal.

For the last command, I get "invalid option."